# Having issues dividing the app screen into halves and/or fractions

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

the below code is one of my many pages for my app. I'm trying to set this page up with the LayoutBuilder so that it'll work like a quiz page with the bottom half/section would hold 3 to 4 TextButtons and the top half/section would hold the question and possibly display a picture.
I did some research and I found that you're able to use the LayoutBuilder to set up containers to be half of the screen. However, when I tried doing that here with this code, I got A LOT of exceptions thrown. So I was wondering if there was a better way to divide the screen in half (or possibly 1/4, 1/4, & 1/2) for a quiz-like layout.
Thank you for your help!

**quiz.dart**

```
class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
const Quiz({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
title: const Text('Quiz'),
),
body: Column(
children: [
Align(alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
child: LayoutBuilder(
builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
return Container(
height: constraints.maxHeight / 2,
// widthdouble.infinity,
);
},
)),
Align(alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
child: LayoutBuilder(
builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
return Container(
height: constraints.maxHeight / 2,
// widthdouble.infinity,
color: const Color.fromRGBO(155, 205, 255, 0.8),
child: Column(children: [
/* TextButton(onPressed: onPressed, child: child),
TextButton(onPressed: onPressed, child: child),
TextButton(onPressed: onPressed, child: child), */
Text('Option A'),
Text('Option B'),
Text('Option C'),
],),
);
},
)),

],
));
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to move the `LayoutBuilder` up, so that you can use the constraints for the children of your `Column`:

[image]

```dart
class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
  const Quiz({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Quiz')),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: constraints.maxHeight / 2,
                color: Colors.green.shade300,
              ),
              Container(
                height: constraints.maxHeight / 2,
                color: Colors.blue.shade300,
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in an easy way with the help of an expanded widget.Create 2 expanded widget with  flex you need so that you can divide the screen as you wish.

```
enter code here

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.amberAccent,
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.lightBlue,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```